# ndk-stack: Unable to open symbol file .../../libutil.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to use the ndk-stack utility to get some help during the 
debug of my app which is using native libraries. The problem is that 
all I get using the utility is this:

> *** *Crash dump:* *****  Build fingerprint:
>   'tmobile/htc_vision/vision:2.3.4/GRJ22/82286:user/  release-keys' 
>   pid: 15769, tid: 15794  >>> us.ihmc.aci.dsproapp <<<  signal 11
>   (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000024  Stack frame #00 
>   pc 00063710  /data/data/us.ihmc.aci.dsproapp/lib/  libutil.so: Unable
>   to open symbol file /home/enrico/CVSROOT/android/ 
>   aci/dsproapp/obj/local/armeabi/libutil.so. **Error (9): Bad file 
>   descriptor**

The command that I'm using is this:

> ndk-stack -sym ../obj/local/armeabi -dump
>   /home/enrico/stacktrace/crash_waypoint.txt

All my native libraries are compiled with

> APP_OPTIM := debug APP_STL := gnustl_static

In the Application.mk, so the debug symbols *should* be present. 
Did anyone of you had this problem before? 
Thanks, 
Enrico

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me while trying to debug a crash in my C code. Scratched my head over this for about 3 hours.

You're probably using the .so file from `{project_root}/libs/arm*/`.
You should use the one fron `{project_root}/obj/local/arm*/`. This one has the symbolic information.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error when the .so file is present but the file does not contain the symbolic imformation. My guess is that your file did not have the symbols generated for it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose

Your Application.mk should be like this :

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

and your Android.mk should be like this :

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -I <Your header files goes here>
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -g
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -ggdb
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -O1
```

Comment: All of these options are on by default. (`APP_OPTIM` doesn't change the debugability of the binaries in the intermediate directory)